# Method Document of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed on a dedicated company server

Tags: excel, vba, webforms, runtime-error

I am trying to fill a web form with Excel data. While the code is working with other sites (like Facebook, Twitter, etc.), it's giving me Run-time Error 2147467259.

I am pretty sure it's because the web form I am trying to fill is based on a dedicated company server.

Here's the first part of my code:

```vb
Sub Test1()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://pkgatepass.pg.com/gatepass/WHgatepass.aspx"
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    IE.Document.getElementbyID("Body_tbxSealNo").Value = "AC102"
End Sub
```

Comment: suggestion: post some code, and the complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little low information from you. Based on:

> I am pretty sure it's because the web form I am trying to fill data
> into is based on a dedicated company server.

Change the line like this:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
```

to this

```
Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
```