# Validate bulk URL and content in it

Tags: excel, vba

I have been seeking to validate bulk URL and content in it. And print the value in B2 cell range.

```
Sub CheckPageData()
 
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim IntExp As Object
    
    Set IntExp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IntExp.Visible = True
 
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A10")
        'Here A2 is cell Address where we have stored urls which we need to test.
        
        If Left(cell.Value, 4) = "http" Then
            
            ' Goto web page
            IntExp.Navigate cell.Text
            
           ' Below loop will run until page is fully loaded
            Do Until IntExp.ReadyState = 4 
            Loop
 
            ' Now use text which you want to search , error text which you want to compare etc.
            If InStr(IntExp.Document.body.innerText, _
               "Text which you want to search or verify") > 0 Then
               
               cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "Result message which you want to give."
 
            Else
               If InStr(IntExp.Document.body.innerText, _
               "The page you requested was not found.") > 0 Then
                  cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "The page you requested was not found."
               End If
 
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
 
    IntExp.Quit
    Set IntExp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing an `End If` right before the other `End If`s

Comment: Can you edit and show ?

Comment: Right after `cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "The page you requested was not found."` put `End If`

Comment: `Range("A2", 5)` is not a valid Range

Comment: @mohammed No one can fix that for you since we do not know what is the intended range, what range are you trying to loop? `A2:A5`?

Comment: Hey thanks for help, but I want to print value into cell how do I do that?

Comment: I have changed cell range A2:A10

Comment: `I want to print value into cell` - What value? and what cell? You have assigned value to a cell before in your code so I doubt that's what you are asking... @mohammedBaig

Comment: @Raymond Wu , I am looking for VBA Script to get status code of provided link (A2) and inner content from same from (B2). And paste the value of status code in (C2)

Comment: Unforunately your lack of details is not helping us as well, what `status code` are you looking for? Error `404` or OK `200` this kind? It will be best if you can provide an example with 1 URL and what are you expecting to see from that URL? Provide a screenshot of it @mohammedBaig

Comment: @RaymondWu link for example is racaty.net/1dvfju36wuym i want to grab data from popup and place the same in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not give sufficient information on what you actually wants, this will loop through `A2:A10` and retrieve the text in the popup (that can be found by using class name `file-info`) and insert in column B:

```
Sub CheckPageData()
 
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim IntExp As Object
    
    Set IntExp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IntExp.Visible = True
 
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A10")
        'Here A2 is cell Address where we have stored urls which we need to test.
        
        If Left(cell.Value, 4) = "http" Then
            
            ' Goto web page
            IntExp.Navigate cell.Text
            
           ' Below loop will run until page is fully loaded
            Do While IntExp.Busy Or IntExp.readyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Loop
 
            ' Now use text which you want to search , error text which you want to compare etc.
            Dim ieDoc As Object
            Set ieDoc = IntExp.Document
            
            If ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("file-info").Length <> 0 Then
                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("file-info")(0).innerText
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
 
    IntExp.Quit
    Set IntExp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting error "Method 'Navigate' of object 'ÍwebBrowser2' failed

Comment: Try `IntExp.Navigate cell.value`

Comment: I am using this link **https://racaty.net/1dvfju36wuym** in Cell A2 & class name ID **text-danger**

Comment: IntExp.Navigate cell.value did not help same error

Comment: not helpful, did you get a chance to identify the issue

Comment: The code is working for me so the issue is on your end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086425/excel-vba-method-document-of-object-iwebbrowser2-failed Might be an issue with your Internet Explorer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217045/method-document-of-object-iwebbrowser2-failed-on-a-dedicated-company-server or try this. It's not possible to tell you what's your issue since the code is working on my end. @mohammedBaig

Comment: dear @RaymondWu thanks the issue was in Internet Explorer. Request your feed back on one more issue how to I added multiple **getElementsByClassName** in the same program as I would be validating multiple links from different domain.

Comment: Usually you will need a sub dedicated to a webpage as each webpage is different, however if you are sure that all the links that you are validating is as simple as the case above (just need to check 1 instance of classname and they are all unique across all links), I suppose you can do multiple If-ElseIf-EndIf statements to check through all the predefined classnames. @mohammedBaig

Comment: If this answer resolves this question, pleas accept it by clicking the tick beside the answer. (You can only accept 1 answer if there are multiple answers submitted) @mohammedBaig

Comment: thanks, will update and check if anything will trouble you again. Much appreciate for your help.

Comment: Please post a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks Raymond issue is resolved by introducing If statement multiple times