# Web scraping - 'IWebBrowser2' failed

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer

Currently, I have provided a dummy website below, and I was using the code below to navigate to the website and enter the value in the specific cell. After running this code, it navigates to the website, but no values are filled in and an error message appears.

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    
    IE.Visible = True
    'IE.navigate "https://www.facebook.com/"
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
     
    
    IE.document.getElementById("WD0282").Value = "1234"
    

End Sub
```

> Error: Run-time error '2147467259 (80004005) Method Document of object
> 'IWebBrowser2' failed

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the line below.

`Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

with the line below.

`Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")`

It could help you fixed the said error.

Helpful reference: [Method Document of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed on a dedicated company server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63217203)

Comment: Using the above code 'IWebBrowser2' failed error is resolved.
Now i'm getting "Run-time error '424': Object required error.
 it's because the web form I am trying to fill is based on a  company website.? or can it be solved

Comment: On which line of VBA code are you getting that error? If possible, please also share the HTML code for the element in which you want to set the value.